# nginx redirect / to /v2/

Tags: nginx, redirect

i have an nginx location defined like that:

```
location / {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/myapp/dist/;
        gzip_static on;

        # Media: images, icons and fonts
        location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|ico|otf)$ {
            expires 2M;
            access_log off;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }

        # CSS, HTML and Javascript
        location ~* \.(?:css|js|html)$ {
            expires 4h;
            access_log off;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }
    }
```

But for some reason alot of users didnt get my last index.html update.
Since this is crucial and alot of users complain i would like to redirct every request from / (/index.html, /#/myTeam) to /v2/ (/v2/index.html, /v2/#/myTeam).
so ill know for sure user cache is not an issue.

Iv'e created a new location called /v2/ and moved everything there, then changed / to:

```
 # Serve locations
 location / {
     return 301 /v2/;
 }
```

But that didnt work.
Also tried several rewrites without luck.
Can i redirect / ?

Comment: You can use another `root` (not `alias`): `root /usr/share/nginx/myapp/dist/v2;`. In this case you don't need any `return` or `rewrite`.

Comment: @uzsolt But in that case from user perspective nothings changed, and because of their cache they still won't get the new version no?

Comment: @uzsolt only if client-side caching isn't going to get in the way.

Comment: Ooops, you've right. I missed this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redirecting every request `/blah/blah/whatever`, to just plain `/v2/` which is not what you wanted.

```
location / {
    return 301 /v2$request_uri;
}
```

will preserve original requested URI prepending it with `/v2/`.